# WPF or WinForms - Draw a complex User Interface

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to build an App with a special UserInterface.
The idea looks like this image:
[image: User Interface]

The big circle in the Middle is the StartPoint. The segments in the outer Circle are options the user can select. But to select an option the outer circle can be rotate and the selection is highlight or expanded on the right side of the inner Circle. But the outer cirlce is only level 1, I built more than one selection and for each selected option there comes the next outer circle with new Options.

Is this even possible in WPF or WinForms?

Regards 
Chris

Comment: Well it is possible if you can draw it. In the end everything you see on a GUI is just some drawing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixels are pixels: you can do it in both ways.

The real question is: what platform offers me the best advantages in terms of simplicity/flexibility of development?

My two-cents answer is: WPF. No doubt.

That's because your goal is dealing with geometries, rotations, animations (maybe). WPF relies on a vector-based approach, which solves better problems like yours, although it might be a bit complex to deal with if you never had an experience.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely WPF. I've made simple games and physics simulations in WPF using transformations and rotations, and WPF makes it fairly painless.

Since you will be adding a lot of those items programatically, Winforms is based around the designer to add elements, so it may not give you the flexibility you would like, whereas WPF is better and more intuitive with run-time changes.